# Using NSFetchRequest to find each users most resent entries

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm using CoreData on iOS to store pings, each entry has |userid, timestamp, outgoing|.

I want to use a NSFetchRequest to get each users most resent 'outgoing' entry (one per user)

The SQL syntax would look something like

```
    SELECT * FROM 
      'Pings' AS P1 WHERE P1.out = 1 AND P1.timestamp = 
      (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM 
        Pings AS P2 HAVING 
        P1.userid = P2.userid AND P2.out = 1)
```

I can't seem to get the translation to NSPredicate to work

Answer (score 1):

While Core Data can use SQLite as a data store it can't leverage 100% of the power and flexibility of SQL queries. If you want to think in terms of tables and sub queries then you should use SQL directly. If you want to work in terms of objects and relationships then you should change your approach.

Specifically, when you add a new outgoing ping, replace the existing relationship from the user object to its `lastPing` object with the new ping just created. Now, to query the items you just query the users you're interested in and read the pings from the relationships.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I actually ended up filtering the result post query in Objective-C since I knew that the table would not contain much more then a few thousand rows